# Creating Libraries for iOS, Android and WP7 based on the same code

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, cross-platform

I already have existing applications written on three platforms in the appropriate languages: objective C, Java and C#, but big parts of the apps are the same for all of them.

So will it be possible to create a .DLL with one of crossplatforms and import it in my Applications?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Xamarin's tool set](http://xamarin.com/) (along with Visual Studio for Phone), you can create assemblies with common code written in C# that can be consumed on all of those platforms.  The actual assembly binary is not portable across the platforms, but the code can be made portable pretty easily as long as it's not UI code.

Answer (score 2):

maybe phonegap, but depends on how much of the hardware resource and os specific features are used. I personally don't like the cross-platform solutions.

My personal option would be to use same configuration files(xml's maybe) and keep the original platform development.

Answer (score 1):

All of them support javascript applications, maybe you could port your app to javascript and HTML5. You would still have some specific code to do, but you would be able to encapsulate your core functionalities and reuse it in all platforms.

Can't see this portability done in other way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible through native code since Windows Phone 7 doesn't allow you to run native code. You can use C code in iOS and Android (using the NDK), but not for Windows Phone 7 as far as I'm aware. You might want to check the Mono project to see if you can reuse C# in iOS and Android. HTML5 is obviously an alternative.